# Twitter OAuth Pin based authorization 'oob' in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, twitter, oauth, google-apps-script, twitter-oauth

I am trying to use [Twitter Pin-based authorization](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/pin-based) in my Google Apps Script to eventually send tweets on behalf of other uses.

I freely admit that I don't relay know what I'm doing but I have read a lot of info on the internet and feel I have tried everything.

My current Google Apps Script JavaScript code:

```
var method = 'post';
var url = 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token';

var consumerKey = '[my consumer key]';

var ticks = '1422745454';
var nonce = '6826266';

var options = {
  'method': method,
  'oauth_callback': 'oob',
  'oauth_consumer_key': consumerKey,
  'oauth_nonce': nonce,
  'oauth_signature': 'cIFeptE5HjHp7xrp%2BZt9xFhHox4%3D',
  'oauth_signature_method': 'HMAC-SHA1',
  'oauth_timestamp': ticks,
  'oauth_version': '1.0'
};

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
```

For testing I set the ticks just before each test run to the value [here](http://www.epochconverter.com/)
The nonce is a random number between 111111 and 9999999 which is regenerated before each test run.
The oauth signature I have been generating with some c# code lifted from the [linq2twitter project](https://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/)

I suspect the problem is the signature. I have read the [twitter documentation on creating a signature](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview/creating-signatures) and I think the C# code is doing it correctly but I am not sure.

The problem is that whatever I try I always get this error:
"Request failed for https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token returned code 401. Truncated server response: Failed to validate oauth signature and token (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)"

I have been trying to find an example of Twitter Pin-based authorization in a Google Apps Script but have so far not found anything.
My attempts to translate examples in C#, PHP, etc. have also failed.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Apps Script provides an Oauth API that works with UrlFetchApp, they even use twitter in their examples.  Work with those if at all possible, troubleshooting signature generation is a real hassle.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/o-auth-config
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/twitter_tutorial

If you absolutely must do it from scratch, the best approach is to get requests working with an existing library (like the c# one you mention), then work on getting your apps script to generate the exact same request.

I get the sense that is what you are doing now, so it may just be a matter of base64 encoding your Signature in the outgoing request:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#base64Encode(String)

Ultimately, it's very difficult to do the whole Oauth process manually in Apps Script. When I tried something like this from scratch about a year ago I ultimately gave up and used a Python application deployed to Google App Engine instead. I submit requests from Apps Script to the App Engine application, and the App Engine application handles Oauth and relays my requests on to the external service, before returning requests to my Apps Script.  This approach comes with complications of it's own.

Comment: Sorry I should have been clearer: I don't necessarily want to do it manually and would much rather use the built-in URLFetchApp Oauth API.  I have been following the twitter examples you linked to and that is how I even got this far. I am able to read and post tweets to my account but it is the PIN-based authorization specifically that is causing me a problem. What I really need is a code example of this working in Apps Script with or without the Oauth API. I did even consider moving everything to App Engine and using a PHP or Python library but as you say, I think that will cause other issues